# Baire principle with open and dense subsets-edited

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

This is a question on the Baire principle for metric spaces.

Let $X$ be a COMPLETE metric space without isolated points. Prove or disprove that, every sequence $(O_n)$ of open and dense subsets of X and every countable set $S$, it holds that $$S\cap (\cap_n O_n)\neq \emptyset$$

Comment: Are you sure the word "if" should be in there? If so, there ought to be a "then" somewhere, no?

Comment: At any rate, what have you tried? What are your thoughts on the problem so far?

Comment: I think this is what you wanted to say? Am I right?

Comment: You are all right. Forgot to add X is complete

Answer (score 1):

Any way, it is wrong...

Consider $X= \mathbb R, O_n= \mathbb {R-Z}$ be a constant sequence of open dense subset of $X$ and consider $S=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: You are right. X must be complete for the result to hold. Thanks

Comment: @Gearclose don't edit question like this, you should ask a separate question if needed

Comment: OK will do :) Thanks!

Comment: @gearclose have a look at the edited answer

Comment: @Gearclose DID YOU GET THIS COUNTER EXAMPLE?